# Force certificate to be stored as machine certificate

Tags: c#, .net, certificate

We have a web portal where a admin user goes to and installs a client certificate on the local windows machine. This certificate is used by our application (C# .Net) to authenticate against a web service. Today it ends up automatically in the current user certificate store.

With a bit limited knowledge about creating certificates, is there a way to specify in the certificate in which store it will end up? I want it to be accessible for any user logged on to the system not just the user installing it. The certificate is "not exportable", is there a way to move it internally to a different store after its been installed?

**Update**:
Some of the machines are connected to our domain and some are not. Some of the customers run a computer with one user account and others with different and we are looking for a solution that works for all of them.

Many thanks

Comment: The current user certificate store is the only store that you are guaranteed to be allowed to install the certificate to.  You don't indicate if these are customers are just users.  If they are internal users just have the IT administrator install the certificate for everyone at once.

Comment: I did a small update to my post, pushing the certificate to the machines are not an option for us.